# hyperref or equivalent - I just want to generate clickable external links

Tags: hyperref

I am hoping this is an easy question with a straightforward answer, but I have been poking around for a while now and I haven't seen any instructions for how to do this:

I just want to add clickable links for URLs, I don't want to generate internal links at all. I have just installed hyperref, and I was hoping there was some nice option called "urlonly" or something but I can't see it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is a section, but I don't want a link in the toc}
I want this link to work. \href{http://news.bbc.co.uk}{BBC news}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Could you please add a minimum (working) example demonstrating your situation?

Comment: I don't think a MWE is relevant - it is a pretty general question relating to the standard behaviour of a package... but if anyone else asks for one, I will!

Comment: Thanks @IanThompson for doing my work for me :) Sorry I was too lazy.

Comment: If the link appearances are disturbing you, then you can use option `hidelinks`.

Comment: Thanks @HeikoOberdiek I was using that already, and I know I can switch off the bookmarks, but I think it is a little odd to have thousands of hidden links throughout a document - someone might click by accident and wonder what on earth happened when they zoom to another part of the document. Maybe I just need to embrace internal hyperlinks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am enclosing my patch. I am partly executing the `draft` option as defined in the `hyperref.sty` file from the `hyperref` bundle with two key lines commented out.

```
%! *latex mal-hyperlinks.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
% Patch: draft option do all this:
\makeatletter
    \let\hyper@@anchor\@gobble
    \gdef\hyper@link#1#2#3{#3\Hy@xspace@end}%
    \def\hyper@anchorstart#1#2{#2\Hy@xspace@end}%
    \def\hyper@anchorend{\Hy@xspace@end}%
    \let\hyper@linkstart\@gobbletwo
    \def\hyper@linkend{\Hy@xspace@end}%
    % \def\hyper@linkurl#1#2{#1\Hy@xspace@end}%
    \def\hyper@linkfile#1#2#3{#1\Hy@xspace@end}%
    % \def\hyper@link@[#1]#2#3#4{#4\Hy@xspace@end}%
    \def\Acrobatmenu#1#2{\leavevmode#2\Hy@xspace@end}%
    \let\PDF@SetupDoc\@empty
    \let\PDF@FinishDoc\@empty
    \let\@fifthoffive\@secondoftwo
    \let\@secondoffive\@secondoftwo
    \let\ReadBookmarks\relax
    \let\WriteBookmarks\relax
    \Hy@WarningNoLine{Draft mode on}%
\makeatother
% End of patch...
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is a section, but I don't want a link in the toc}
\label{test}Cross-reference~\ref{test} on page~\pageref{test}. Cited book is~\cite{mybook}.\par
I want this link to work. \href{http://news.bbc.co.uk/}{BBC news}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{mybook} A book about\ldots
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Fantastic. Messy to have to include all that code, but fantastic! I guess I just have to persuade @HeikoOberdiek that this is an option that would be useful to more people than just me!

Comment: While I wouldn't use it in anything I'm working on at the moment I should think it would be a valid option, worth including.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer to my own question: I use `cleveref` and I only just noticed the part of the documentation that says to use the starred variants `\cref*{}`when combining with `hyperref if you don't want the references to generate links.

I doubt this would have helped solve my MWE though, as I am sure the table of contents works differently, but I thought it would potentially help others in my position to know that most of my internal linking issues could have been fixed with this answer!